# Which track is playing in S2E1 of Ansatsu Kyoushitsu?

Tags: music, assassination-classroom

In the 1st episode of Ansatsu Kyoushitsu [Assassination Classroom] season 2,
an instrumental track plays in the background from 5:20 to 5:50. If anyone knows its name, please tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is "Irina no Koigokoro", which is track 5 on [the special CD bundled with S2 BD2](http://vgmdb.net/album/58512) (EYXA-10829B). [Here](https://clyp.it/tglyjy1y?token=31658c13c0ac8a4c89607aa067e697ce) is a 15-second extract from the beginning of the track.

Seems like an odd piece to be playing in a sequence where Karma and Manami are talking (not about Irina), but it is what it is.

Comment: Seems like it is an unreleased track